# Displaying a Directory with CefSharp

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

Using CefSharp 63 (WinForms), I can navigate to a local folder by doing a `Load()` like so:

```
var folder = @"c:\fonts";
browser.Load(folder);
```

It works by automatically translating the request to `file:///C:/fonts`, but the result is ugly. It seems like an un-evaluated HTML template for the directory listing is displayed, where various placeholders have not been filled in.

Here is an example (in a simple test application):

[image]

Is there a way to intercept this template and style it, fill in the placeholders, etc?

Yes, I am aware that I can replace the default behavior by creating my own scheme handler and doing anything I want with it, but I am looking to leverage the built-in local directory browsing capability, rather than rolling out my own.

Is there a way?

Comment: You'd have to dig through the Chromium source, you might get away with editing the pak files.

Comment: @amaitland Looks like it would be simpler to just create a scheme. Thanks.